# Difference between MessageBus and Servicebus?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Is there a difference between a MessageBus and a ESB? 
I do some Research for my degree and can Not find an article that Shows the difference between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message bus is one of the enterprise Integration Pattern.

ESB has also been used to refer to the message bus enterprise integration pattern. but growing number of companies began marketing their EAI and MOM products as ESBs, the term has generally **been associated with a class of product, rather than an architectural pattern**.
Different vendor and forums have their own take on ESB definitions. you can choose your favorite one.

The below link sheds light on your topic.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa475433(v=bts.10).aspx